# Directshow - Identify built-in (integrated camera) vs external USB camera

Tags: windows, camera, webcam, directshow, windows-8.1

Are there any PC camera hardware experts who happen to know if a built-in (intergrated) camera on a PC has any special identifying features , as opposed to an external USB camera?

I'm looking for anything that would help me ascertain for sure that the device is indeed built-in to the PC and was not connected by the user.

I've gone over every device property in the device manager for both kinds of webcams but could not identify anything helpful.

Even something as simple as a USB connection order (maybe the built-in camera would be "connected" first on boot?)

I'm a USB noob so please bear with me...

Comment: I don't think there is a specific indication. A camera would be typically a USB-like device.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can do that. On some laptop models, the "internal camera" is in fact wired to an internal usb hub. This is what I realized when I opened my ASUS EEE 901 a few years ago. I am pretty sure this is a common scheme since many camera dev kits come with usb output

Comment: What about USB connection order? maybe the internal camera would be connected "first"?

Comment: Most likely the internal camera will be connected first but this is not guaranteed! It depends on the order in which the OS queries the various USB hubs